Problemas con programa de creación y login de usuarios (básico)
Estoy teniendo problemas a tratar de hacer que la función reconozca el login de usuario y contraseña que hice. Me lo toma como que es incorrecto.
Tampoco entiendo de qué forma poder agregar mas clave y valores al diccionario creado para que pueda guardarlo. Si le pido un nuevo usuario la funcion sobreescribe el anterior que estaba hecho.
Si alguien sabe como me podrían guiar seria genial, estoy trabado.
def almacenar_datos():
    print("BIENVENIDO AL PROGRAMA DE CREACION DE USUARIOS!!")
    while True:
        almacenar = {}
        
        user = input("Digame su nombre de usuario que quiere utilizar: ")
        pwd = input("Digame su contraseña: ")

        almacenar[user] = pwd

        print("Gracias por registrarse!!!")

        seguir = input("Desea seguir agregando usuarios? \n (si/no)")
    

        if seguir.lower() != "si":
            print("PROGRAMA FINALIZADO")
            break
    return almacenar  

usuarios_registrados = almacenar_datos()

def login_usuarios():

    print("BIENVENIDO AL PROGRAMA DE INICIO DE SESION!!!")

    print(usuarios_registrados)
    while True:

        user_ = input("Coloque su usuario: ")
        pwd_ = input("Coloque su contraseña: ")

        if user_ == usuarios_registrados.keys() and pwd_ == usuarios_registrados.values():
            print("Inicio de sesion exitosa")
            
        else:
            print("Usuario o contraseña incorrecta, intentelo nuevamente!")
            
            seguir_ = input("Desea cerrar sesion?\n(si/no)")
            if seguir_.lower() == "si":
                print("PROGRAMA FINALIZADO")
                break

login_usuarios()


El problema de almacenar más de un item en el diccionario se resuelve simplemente creando el diccionario fuera del ciclo:
almacenar = {}
while True:    
    user = input("Digame su nombre de usuario que quiere utilizar: ")
    pwd = input("Digame su contraseña: ")

Tal como lo estás haciendo creas un nuevo objeto dict y lo reasignas a la variable almacenar en cada iteración del ciclo. El anterior diccionario será destruido (recolectado por el GC) y el nuevo solo contendrá la pareja clave: valor agregada en esa iteración.
En cuanto al problema de que no te reconoce como válido el usuario y su clave, es que simplemente estás buscando mal en el diccionario.
dict.keys() y dict.values() retornan una lista con las claves y valores del diccionario (en realidad retornan lo que se conoce como vista y no una lista, pero eso no importa para esta respuesta). Al hacer:
user_ == usuarios_registrados.keys()

estás comparando una cadena (user_) con la lista de todas las claves del diccionario. Eso es siempre False porque, para empezar, son objetos distintos, de distinto tipo. Es la misma razón por la que:
>>> "Hola" == ["Hola"]  # str == list[str]
False

Para saber si un objeto está dentro de un iterable se usa el operador de pertenencia, in:
>>> lista = [4, 7, 9]
>>> 7 in lista
True
>>> 3 in lista
False

Podrías por tanto hacer:
if user_ in usuarios_registrados.keys() and pwd_ in usuarios_registrados.values():

pero no lo hagas, eso tiene dos problemas:

Ese condicional comprueba si user_ está en el diccionario (es una de sus claves) y si  pwd_ está en sus valores, pero no comprueba que pwd_ sea la clave de ese usuario en concreto, cosa que seguramente quieres... Por ejemplo:
>>> usuarios_registrados = {"Pepe": "123", "Ana": "anita"}
>>> user = "Pepe"
>>> pwd = "anita"
>>> user in usuarios_registrados.keys() and pwd in usuarios_registrados.values()
True

Perfecto, Pepe se ha autentificado usando la clave de Ana...

Los diccionarios usan tablas hash, la principal ventaja es que son muy eficientes a la hora de buscar un item (clave) en ellos. En un array o lista tienes que recorrer el iterable item a item desde el principio y hasta el final (en el peor de los casos) para encontrar un item en el mismo. En el caso de las tablas hash esto no es así. Si usas clave in dict.keys() te cargas de un plumazo esta ventaja.


Para ver si una clave está en un diccionario usa simplemente:
if clave in diccionario:

Para obtener el valor asociado a una clave en concreto:
valor = diccionario[clave]

Por lo tanto, en tu caso, puedes hacer:
if user_ in usuarios_registrados and usuarios_registrados[user_] == pwd_:


if user_ in usuarios_registrados comprueba si el usuario existe (la clave user_ está en el diccionario).

Si existe (and), usuarios_registrados[user_] == pwd_ comprueba si la clave de ese usuario en concreto (usuarios_registrados[user_] obtiene el valor de la clave user_) es la misma que pwd_.


Tienes más opciones, por ejemplo intentar obtener el valor directamente y manejar la excepción si el usuario no existe (KeyError), usar dict.get()...

Se esta sobreescrbiendo porque la variable almacenar esta dentro del while, por lo que se esta limpiando con cada ciclo del while lo que puedes hacer es sacarlo del while:
def almacenar_datos():
         print("BIENVENIDO AL PROGRAMA DE CREACION DE USUARIOS!!")
         almacenar = {}
         while True:

y sobre la validación del usuario es porque estas comparando una variable que tienen un valor individual con todos los valores de usuarios_registrados.keys(), aunque solo este uno lo toma como si fueran varios por lo que siempre será False, lo que puedes hacer es buscar el usuario en la variable usuario_registrado y comparar la contraseña, de esta manera:
if usuarios_registrados[user] == pwd:
        print("Inicio de sesion exitosa")


Gracias lo voy a probar, muchas gracias en serio.

la respuesta a ambas cosas es sencilla, tienes que sacar la declaración de almacenar fuera del while y junto a esto añado un consejo de programación, no hagas un while(true), es mejor otra condición que haga que se termine pero sin usar break, por ejemplo que sea la variable respuesta = "si"(declarándola fuera del bucle y usando input para cambiarla dentro del bucle) while(respuesta == "si")

Dale muchas gracias, lo voy a probar
